# cannot set gcc to customize one for cmake

Tags: gcc, cmake

I am new to use cmake. I have installed gcc 4.7 in my home directory.
And I try to set gcc to this location by `export CXX` or overwrite the variable `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER`. The error `cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++11"` still exists. May I know how can I do to solve it?

Comment: Try using `-std=c++0x`.

Comment: Can you try on command-line: cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/path/to/g++-4.7 -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/path/to/gcc-4.7

Comment: It works with -D. But Why?